# Slider component does not work with my library item

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, components, flash-cs5

for some reason a slider extension (slide bar ) works fine in a code but not with my code 
I just want to get the value of the slider and use it to change a voice tone I am using fl and flash libraries for this mobile app.

Why I can not take a value of an attribute from the fl library (object) and use it directly or indirectly in the flash object ?

my code :

```
  import flash.media.Microphone;
   import fl.events.SliderEvent;
   var mic:Microphone;
   gian_sildebar.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, gianvalue);//error

  //Access of undefined property rate_sildebar.

  function setmic():void
   {
    var gainnumber:int=0;
gainnumber= gian_sildebar.value;//error yet "value" is int
mic.setGain(gainnumber);//error
}
```

while the other code was implemented only by using fl libraries and it works without any issues what so ever using the same addEventListener ?! 
thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1):

Few Problems:

- You have never initialized **mic**, so it is null. Use [getMicrophone](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#getMicrophone%28%29) function to get mic instance.
- The function [setGain](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/hpdocs/help.html?content=00000153.html) is not applicable to ActionScript 3. Use [gain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#gain) property instead.

Assuming slider is a instance of [Slider](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/Slider.html) (& is in scope), the correct code should look something like this:

```
import flash.media.Microphone;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;

var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, setmic);

function setmic(e:SliderEvent):void {

    mic.gain = slider.value as Number;  
}
```